How to write the following conditional in a mathematical notation?
I'm trying to write the following in some comprehensible mathematical notation for a paper.
I have 2 square non-symmetric matrices $A,B$:
I need to create a symmetric version of these and for A it is simple
$A_{sym} = \max{(A,A^\top)}$, where max should be understood as elementwise comparison between the two matrices.
The problem is that for B, I want to use the same "indexing" as used in A, meaning I need something like that:
$I = \text{argmax}(A,A^\top)$
and then somehow write that I create $B_{sym}$ by selecting elements from among the two matrices $(B,B^\top)$ based on the indices in $I$.
So something like:
$B_{sym} = (B,B^\top)[I]$
However, this does not seem quite right.
Essentially I am trying to mathematically write the conditional operation:
$B_{sym} = \text{np.where}(A \geq A^\top, B, B^\top)$
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

These sorts of element-by-element operations are not something that comes up in mathematical contexts that often, as we are mostly concerned with matrices as linear operators on vector spaces. So there is no standard notations for them that you can expect everyone to recognize. You will need to add an explicit definition to your paper. I suggest something like: for all $i,j$, $$[B_{sym}]{i,j} = \begin{cases}[B]{i,j}&[A]{i,j} \ge [A]{j, i}\ [B]{j,i}&[A]{i,j} < [A]_{j, i}\end{cases}$$
